# Read video files frame by frame with Dask?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm wondering if Dask would be a good tool for processing video files. Locally I'm using OpenCV to read each frame one at a time and process it. I think it would be ideal if each frame of video was processed by a separate Dask task. Also, for multiple time synchronized video files I'm wondering how I could read one frame at a time from each camera and process the two camera's frames in one task.

I don't think Dask supports generator functions, but if it did somehow I think that would be ideal. A generator task would yield one frame of video at a time into the task graph.

Here's an example script that is similar to what I'm doing. It takes one frame from each of multiple video files, crops and resizes each one to a standard size then aggregates those into one video. In this example, I'm using a fixed crop of [0:512, 0:512], but in the actual script this would vary by camera and frame.

```py
import glob

import cv2
import progressbar
import numpy as np

video_files = {f[0]: f for f in glob.glob('*.MOV')}

in_videos = {}
for letter, in_video_filename in video_files.items():
    in_videos[letter] = cv2.VideoCapture(in_video_filename)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4', fourcc, 120, (256, 256 * len(in_videos)))

for frame_id in progressbar.progressbar(range(18000)):
    image = np.zeros((256 * len(in_videos), 256, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i, (letter, in_video) in enumerate(in_videos.items()):
        success, in_image = in_video.read()
        image[i * 256:(i + 1) * 256, :, :] = cv2.resize(in_image[0:512, 0:512], (256, 256))

    video.write(image)
```

Comment: It looks like some people are thinking about this type of thing over here: https://github.com/dask/dask-image/issues/134

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're looking for either [Dask Delayed](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html) or [Dask Futures](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html)

Comment: I think the main issue is that I don't want to load the whole video file into memory at once because these are large videos. I'd like to only load enough frames from the video to saturate the workers and then reclaim that memory when it isn't needed any more. Not sure how delayed or futures will help with that, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: I recommend adding a very small bit of python pseudo-code into your question of what you do today.  I'm guessing that you call some function that gets a frame out of your video and does something to it.  You could delay that call and call many of them in parallel.

Comment: If your question is "How do I process video with Dask" then that is too broad.  There are probably thousands of ways.  You'll probably need to be more specific about the kind of workfow that you're trying to parallelize.  http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports

Comment: I recommend that you read through this example: https://examples.dask.org/applications/evolving-workflows.html